# Update HTML table with delay after restarting terminal

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I created Flask application to add or delete data from database and display this data in the HTML table. Everything works, I can add data, I can delete it. Issue is that when I do that browser/HTML do not update it straight away and I need push CTRL+S in VSC, to force restart terminal and only after that my table is updated. Code itself is working, but I can`t find why I have such delay. Any thoughts why I have such issue?

My code:

```
@app.route("/skill_delete/<int:id>")
def skill_delete(id):
    skill_to_delete = Skill.query.get_or_404(id)

    try:
        db.session.delete(skill_to_delete)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Skill deleted successfully")
        return redirect(url_for('admin_view'))

    except:
        flash("FAILED")
        return redirect(url_for('admin_view'))
```

Tried clear cache, change localhost.

Comment: when you clear cache from browser does it work?

Comment: no, it dont work when I clear it

Answer (score 0):

first I would advice to use JavaScript inside your script to send POST requests instead requesting the redirect everytime.

One problem I have found is the fact you don't close your SQL connection.

Comment: I have similar app with only adding data and it`s working just fine app.routes are same, so dont know why they behave differently